# Dependencies issues composer [ sonata admin ; SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle]

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, sonata-admin

This morning when i have tried to run composer update , i got the following error:

How can i fix the error ?

> Problem 1
>       - The requested package sonata-project/admin-bundle ~2.4@dev could not be fo und.
>   Problem 2
>       - sonata-project/page-bundle dev-master requires sonata-project/admin-bundle  ~2.4 -> no matching package found.
>       - sonata-project/page-bundle dev-master requires sonata-project/admin-bundle  ~2.4 -> no matching package found.
>       - Installation request for sonata-project/page-bundle dev-master -> satisfia ble by sonata-project/page-bundle[dev-master].
>
> Potential causes:
>    - A typo in the package name
>    - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your min imum-stability setting.

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",

    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",

        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",

        "twig/twig": "1.24.0",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.3",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.12",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "leafo/lessphp": "*",
        "twitter/bootstrap": "*",
        "mremi/contact-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "2.3.*",
        "symfony-cmf/routing-bundle": "~1.1",
        "genemu/form-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "components/jquery": "1.9.*",
        "components/jqueryui": "1.11.4",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3",
        "hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.4.*@dev",
        "knplabs/gaufrette": "~0.1.6",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "dev-master",


        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.4@dev",
        "sonata-project/page-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
        "sonata-project/block-bundle": "2.3.9",
        "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
        "sonata-project/core-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
        "sonata-project/notification-bundle":  "2.3.*@dev",
        "sonata-project/seo-bundle":  "2.0.*@dev",
        "sonata-project/cache-bundle":  "2.2.*@dev",
        "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "~2.1",
        "sonata-project/comment-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
        "sonata-project/ecommerce": "dev-develop",



        "zendframework/zend-crypt"          : "dev-master",
        "white-october/pagerfanta-bundle": "dev-master",
        "pagerfanta/pagerfanta": "1.0.*@dev",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "ensepar/html2pdf-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "lexxpavlov/pagebundle": "~1.0",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "dev-master",
        "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "3.0",
        "stfalcon/page-bundle": "*",
        "stephanecollot/datetimepicker-bundle": "dev-master",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "6.2.x-dev",
        "omnipay/paypal": "~2.0",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.7.0",
        "jms/payment-paypal-bundle": "1.0.0",
        "jms/payment-core-bundle": "dev-master",
        "payum/payum-bundle": "1.0",
        "payum/offline": "*@stable",
        "payum/core": "1.0.*"
        "payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp": "1.2.0",
        "payum/paypal-pro-checkout-nvp": "1.3.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found a way to fix my issue:

I replaced This:

```
"sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
"sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.4@dev",
```

by this :

```
 "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "3.x-dev as 2.4",
 "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "3.x-dev as 2.4",
```

For more information you can check the link bellow:

[here](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/3731#issuecomment-212636270)